# jquery UI Draggable Snap and Snap Tolerance Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, eventtrigger

I'm using jquery UI draggable on a toolbar element and enabling snap in order to snap it to the four edges of my container when dragged around.  I want to do two things but don't know where to start.

1)  When the toolbar element comes within the edge proximity I want to display an dashed 'ghost' outline of the toolbar where it is about to be snapped to.

2)  Once the user actually snaps the toolbar element to the edge I need to trigger an event to do several things, like rotate the toolbar from a horizontal orientation to a vertical one if being snapped from a top/bottom edge to a left/right edge.

I can worry about the logic involved inside these functions to do the actions I need but I'm wondering how to trigger these events.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?